# Check All Child Records Exists Or Not Of Parent Id In Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Table A :

```
PRID  PRTRNSID
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     1
2     2
```

In this table , For PRID 1 there are 3 child records and For PRID 2 there are 2 child records

Table B :

```
EVENTTRNID PRID PRTRNSID
 1            1    1
 2            1    2
 3            2    1
 4            2    2
```

In this table , all child records for prid 2 is exists while for prid 1,3rd number child record is missing ,so i need output in following way

OutPut :

```
PRID  Status
1     Pending
2     Done
```

Can anyone help me for check all child ids exists in another table or not  ?

Comment: Please provide some explanation about your question

Comment: Can you please explain what are the child ids and what is the status field in the output. It will be good if you provide further information about every field's explanation in order for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
with A as (select 1 PRID, 1 PRTRNSID from dual
          union all
          select 1, 2 from dual
          union all
          select 1, 3 from dual
          union all
          select 2, 1 from dual
          union all
          select 2, 2 from dual),
     B as (select 1 EVENTTRNID, 1 PRID, 1 PRTRNSID from dual
          union all
          select 2, 1, 2 from dual
          union all
          select 3, 2, 1 from dual
          union all
          select 4, 2, 2 from dual)

select A.prid, case when min(case when B.EVENTTRNID is null then 0 else B.EVENTTRNID end) = 0 then 'Pending' else 'Done' end Status
  from A left join B on B.PRID = A.PRID and B.PRTRNSID = A.PRTRNSID
 group by A.prid
```